# Add custom view to the right of toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am trying to achieve this(A timer in `toolbar` with red background):

[image: A timer in the toolbar along with red background]

I am trying to add `customView` in `toolbar`. It always end's up being on extreme left just beside the back arrow. Like the text `YP` in image below is a custom `Textview` added to toolbar.[image].

The code for `toolbar`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/base_activity_toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

The code for adding the layout:

```
    LayoutInflater mInflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.textview, null);
    toolbar.addView(mCustomView);
```

This is the layout I am adding right now for testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="end"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:text="yp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am missing something majorly, could not figure out. Pulling my hairs out.

Comment: Change the LinearLayout's `layout_width` to `match_parent`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can add `ViewGroups` inside `Toolbar`

```
          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <RelativeLayout
             ....
            </RelativeLayout>

           </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: When I do something like this, though, I see the TextView I've added but it no longer shows the Toolbar title. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you specified  `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`? or might be the `TextView` overlaid the toolbar title.

Comment: Yes because the `RelativeLayout` gets added to the left of the Toolbar title. Specially if you add `alignParentRight="true"`, it pushes the title out of view. I have added another answer to address this issue, a comment with all that code would be too long.

Answer (score 30):

I just set layout_gravity to the `right`and it worked

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    app:title="NEW REQUESTS"
  >
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="blahblah"
      android:layout_gravity="right"  
      />
  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I can't believe it, that actually worked! A.S. doesn't give layout_gravity as an option for TextView inside a Toolbar, so I hadn't tried it.

Comment: @Anarchofascist, yes you are right it doesn't give layout_gravity option inside Toolbar, but if you will put it by yourself, it would be accepted.

Answer (score 10):

Given answers work but if you want to set a title to the toolbar (most likely you will), then adding a `RelativeLayout` pushes the title out of view to the right. In this case you need to disable the toolbar title by setting `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)` and add a custom TextView next to the other view you wish to add to Toolbar. 
So as an example you would add a `ImageView` this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/base_activity_toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custom_toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            style="@style/ActionBarTitle"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/custom_toolbar_title"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: works well, for those who need `style="@style/ActionBarTitle"` there is                 `style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"`

Answer (score 8):

Just had the same issue but I found a simpler (in my humble opinion) solution.

You can slightly change your code from :

> ```
> LayoutInflater mInflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
> View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.textview, null);
> toolbar.addView(mCustomView);
> ```

To :

```
LayoutInflater mInflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.textview, null);
toolbar.addView(mCustomView, new Toolbar.LayoutParams(Gravity.RIGHT));
```

The view is then added with gravity set to the right !

Comment: Nice one this was the perfect solution if you are building views programmatically. Thank you

Comment: Perfect solution ! Works like a charm

Comment: Worked perfectly. I had to change the parent layout of R.layout.textview to FrameLayout

Answer (score 0):

give it a try. change R.layout.textview to

```
 <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TV"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply go for

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
 ...>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:text="text aligned right" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```